# How to split mutipart SMS into single SMSs?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

According to telco requirment, I have to split multipart sms into many single sms. For example, if SMS length is of 350 characters, I have to send three different submit_sm and will receive 3 diferent deliver_sm msges of length 159, 159 and 32 instead of three submit_sm of 153, 153 and 44 with one deliver_sm. I hope the question is clear now.

Please help me in this issue.

PS: I am working on kannel.

Answer (score 0):

To send a multipart message you would have to format it with a User Data Header (UDH)

the UDH is made up as follows

05 - Length of UDH

00 - Type of SMS 00 = Multipart

03 - Length of header

D9 - Unique Code (Random)

02 - Total Number of messages

01 - This Messages Position

**MESSAGE 1 in HEX**

The first message sends a whole lot of A's
Note the UDH in bold 050003D90201

DCS is 0 ESM is 64

```
**050003D90201**4141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141
```

**MESSAGE 2 in HEX**

The second message sends a couple of A's with a few C's, note the UDH, this message is also sent using ESM 64

```
**050003D90202**41414141414141414343434343
```